# Notification works but no sound

Tags: ios, notifications

I'm trying to put this code under AppDelegate.m to test local notification :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{    
    NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:5];
    UIApplication* thisApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification* notify = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (notify){
        notify.fireDate = alertTime;
        notify.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notify.repeatInterval = 0;
        notify.alertBody = @"This is notification";
        [thisApp scheduleLocalNotification:notify];
    }
}
```

but I don't hear any sound just like any other applications. should we provide our own sound? can't we use Apple native sound for our notification?

and how to setup 'title text' of notification? because what I see is only `notify.alertBody = @"This is notification";` which produce nothing on title, but 'Notification' as title.

thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sound**

You need to specify that you want a sound by either specifying your own sound file name, or the default. [From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW8):

> For this property, specify the filename (including extension) of a sound resource in the application’s main bundle or UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName to request the default system sound. When the system displays an alert for a local notification or badges an application icon, it plays this sound. The default value is nil (no sound). Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not supported. If you specify a file with a sound that plays over 30 seconds, the default sound is played instead.

**Title**

You cannot modify the title of the notification. It will always be your app name so that a user knows exactly where the notification is coming from.